# Как в Drupal использовать ajax

Tags: php, ajax, drupal

Хочу на странице сайта (сайт сделан на Drupal 7) использовать radiobutton или просто кнопки для переключения содержимого страницы. Нашла вот такой пример:
Содержимое файла index.html.

```
<html>  
<head>  
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; Charset=UTF-8">  
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>  
</head>  

<body>  

    <p>Какую страницу желаете открыть?</p>  
    <form>  
        <input id="btn1" type="button" value="Страница 1">   
        <input id="btn2" type="button" value="Страница 2">  
    </form>  
    <div id="content"></div>  

    <script>  
        $(document).ready(function(){  

            $('#btn1').click(function(){  
                $.ajax({  
                    url: "page1.html",  
                    cache: false,  
                    success: function(html){  
                        $("#content").html(html);  
                    }  
                });  
            });  

            $('#btn2').click(function(){  
                $.ajax({  
                    url: "page2.html",  
                    cache: false,  
                    success: function(html){  
                        $("#content").html(html);  
                    }  
                });  
            });  

        });  
    </script>  

</body>  
</html>
```

но на друпал он не работает... Как быть? Что делать?

Comment: а куда вы это все вставляете? почему page1.html, а не /page1.html -?

Comment: вставляю код на новую страницу (создать основную страницу -> там выбираю php-код), даже если прописать полные адреса до скрипта и страниц, то скрипт вылазит на страницу не выполненный, а как есть

Comment: Посмотрите на ошибки в console. У вас должен быть подключен jQuery. В общем случае, функция $() в Drupal не работает. Вместо нее надо использовать jQuery(). Но, я думаю, что Вам подойдет способ, который я описал в ответе.

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос: "Как в Drupal использовать ajax" - очень общий, т.к. ответов на него может быть не один десяток, в зависимости от контекста.

Если я правильно понял конечную цель, то думаю, что подойдет модуль [QuickTabs](https://www.drupal.org/project/quicktabs). В нем можно сделать закладки, в которые можно поместить различные сущности drupal, и переключать их без перезагрузки страницы.